# Is it possible to deploy GAE static files without deploying the dynamic code?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while, but I cannot find a solution.

My problem is that I have a GAE app running Java and some static files in the webapp/ folder.

When I deploy, I deploy the entire project (that includes compiling Java, deploying server code, etc.) in addition to build my static front end files and move them to the server.

I want to be able to just deploy the static files WITHOUT compiling Java, deploying server code etc.

Is it possible? I am not quite sure how google distributes my static content, but I would like to know.

And most important: I am looking for a solution where I don't need to set up an additional static file server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could serve static content directly from GCS: [Serving from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/serving-static-files#serving_from_cloud_storage) - but then that's no longer GAE :)

The closest way you can get to your goal on GAE that I can think of is to split your app in 2 services/modules, which can be deployed independently of each-other:

- one would contain the static files (having a minimal app code, probably just returning 404s for pretty much anything) - building such service code *should* be minimal as well.
- one would run the code for the app serving dynamic pages

The static content is uploaded with the module/app code but handed over to GAE's infrastructure which will take care of serving it directly, like a CDN - requests for static content are not even reaching your app anymore.

More info: [Serving Static Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/serving-static-files). Also be aware of the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Deployments) covering both code and static files *together*.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for answering my question. I was hoping it was possible to do something like "copy all the static files in webapp/build/ to the server" or something. Guess I'll have to set up GCS or Amazon S3 bucket som something :)